# Grails asset pipeline exclude not working

Tags: angularjs, grails, asset-pipeline, karma-jasmine

I have a project on Grails and angular.js. Also I have tests which runs on karma+jasmin. My directory structure is:

- grails-app

  - assets

    - images
    - javascripts
    - locales
    - stylesheets
    - test

On production all my assets are building on bamboo. The problem is that I want to exclude from compiling test folder with all that inside of it and can't do that.

In my Config.groovy I've added

```
grails.assets.excludes = ["test/**/(*.js|*.json)"]
```

Also I've tried different patterns for exclude and they all not working.
While building I see that all files inside test folder are being compiled+uglified which I don't want since those are node modules and so on.